# Laravel Query Builder Select with empty Input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm building up a filterable list with Laravel 5.0 and I'm crashing on following Problem.

I get the filter parameters from a HTML form and pass them to the Query Builder, but if a form input stays empty **all** rows of the table filtered by the other filters should be returned.

Example code:

```
$collection = Model::withTrashed()
    ->where('attr1', 'LIKE', \Request::input('attr1', '%'))
    ->where('attr2', 'LIKE', \Request::input('attr2', '%'))
    ->where('attr3', 'LIKE', \Request::input('attr3', '%'))
    ->get();
```

This seems to be most correct code for me, but it doesn't work as expected. Do you know a good solution for my Problem? I don't want to integrate a messy switch/case statement for proofing for existence and building the collection up manually. :(

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that you are always passing the filters to the query and you should only pass them if they are not empty.

Maybe somethig like this would work for you:

```
$results = Model::withTrashed();
if (\Request::input('attr1')) {
    $results->where('attr1', 'LIKE', \Request::input('attr1', '%'));
}
if (\Request::input('attr2')) {
    $results->where('attr2', 'LIKE', \Request::input('attr2', '%'))
}
if (\Request::input('attr3')) {
    $results->where('attr3', 'LIKE', \Request::input('attr3', '%'))
}
$collection = $results->get();
```

Comment: I guess I have to use it this way. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tweak your query a bit like this:

`$collection = Model::withTrashed()
    ->where('attr1', 'LIKE', '%' . \Request::input('attr1') . '%')
    ->where('attr2', 'LIKE', '%' . \Request::input('attr2') . '%')
    ->where('attr3', 'LIKE', '%' . \Request::input('attr3') . '%')
    ->get();`

This will make sure that the `LIKE` clause is still correct when an empty input parameter is sent.

Comment: But doesn't it returns model with attr1 == 11, when I enter 1 in attr1 input?

Comment: Yes, it would, as that is the goal of using `LIKE`. If you don't want that, then you shouldn't use `LIKE` but rather `where('attr1', \Request::input('attr1'))`. In that case you need an if-statement to check for existence of `attr1` in the request.

Comment: But then it returns only rows with attr1 == empty, if nothing was selected in attr1 input. :D

Comment: Indeed, that's why I mentioned that you need to check for existence of the `attr1` parameter in the input.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Thanks for you help! :)